# How to properly append several svg elements to html document?

Tags: javascript, dom, svg

I can't figure out why svg element is appended only once while I ask to append it three times in the loop? Here is the code:

```
var svgchart = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
svgchart.setAttribute('style', 'border: 1px solid grey');
svgchart.setAttribute('class', 'chart');
svgchart.setAttribute('width',100);
svgchart.setAttribute('height',100);
svgchart.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/", "xmlns:xlink", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink");
 var test=[2,6,8];
 for (var i=0; test.length>i; i++)
 {
     var svgappend=document.getElementById("test");
     svgappend.appendChild(svgchart);
 }
```

And here is jsfiddle -- http://jsfiddle.net/ASvb3/

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that appendChild appends *that exact* child. So it *moves* the svg element to a new parent. To fix this, you need to create a new svg element and insert that. So the code that creates the svg should be inside the loop as well:

```
 var test=[2,6,8];
 for (var i=0; test.length>i; i++)
 {
    var svgchart = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
    svgchart.setAttribute('style', 'border: 1px solid grey');
    svgchart.setAttribute('class', 'chart');
    svgchart.setAttribute('width',100);
    svgchart.setAttribute('height',100);
    svgchart.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/", "xmlns:xlink", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink");
     var svgappend=document.getElementById("test");
     svgappend.appendChild(svgchart);
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GolezTrol/ASvb3/1/

If you use JQuery, you can use the `clone()` method to clone the svg element.